# Problem of converting byte order for unsigned 64-bit number in C

Tags: c, gcc, uint32

I am playing with little endian/big endian conversion and found something that a is a bit confusing but also interesting.

In first example, there is no problem using bit shift to convert byte order for type of `uint32_t`. It basically cast a `uint32_t` integer to an array of `uint8_t` and try to access each byte and bit shift.

Example #1:

```
uint32_t htonl(uint32_t x)
{
    uint8_t *s = (uint8_t*)&x;
    return (uint32_t)(s[0] << 24 | s[1] << 16 | s[2] << 8 | s[3]);
}
```

However, if I try to do something similar on a `uint64_t` below, the compiler throws a warning about 's[0] width is less than 56 bits` as in Example #2 below.

Example #2:

```
uint64_t htonl(uint64_t x)
{
    uint8_t *s = (uint8_t*)&x;
    return (uint64_t)(s[0] << 56 ......);
}
```

To make it work, I have to fetch each byte into a `uint64_t` so I can do bit shift without any errors as in Example #3 below.

Example #3:

```
uint64_t htonll2(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t byte1 = x & 0xff00000000000000;
    uint64_t byte2 = x & 0x00ff000000000000;         
    uint64_t byte3 = x & 0x0000ff0000000000;
    uint64_t byte4 = x & 0x000000ff00000000;
    uint64_t byte5 = x & 0x00000000ff000000;
    uint64_t byte6 = x & 0x0000000000ff0000;                                                                                              
    uint64_t byte7 = x & 0x000000000000ff00;
    uint64_t byte8 = x & 0x00000000000000ff;

    return (uint64_t)(byte1 >> 56 | byte2 >> 40 | byte3 >> 24 | byte4 >> 8 |
                      byte5 << 8  | byte6 << 24 | byte7 << 40 | byte8 << 56);
}
```

I am a little bit confused by `Example #1` and `Example #2`, as far as I understand, both `s[i]` is of `uint8_t` size, but somehow if it only shift 32 bits or less there is no problem at all, but there is an issue when shifting like 56 bits. I am running this program on Ubuntu with GCC 8.3.0.

Does the compiler implicitly convert `s[i]` into 32-bit numbers in this case?  `sizeof(s[0])` is 1 when I added debug messages to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `s[0]` expression has an 8-bit wide integral type, which is promoted to a 32-bit unsigned integer when operated on by the shift operator – so `s[0] << 24` in the first example works OK, as the shift by 24 does not exceed the `uint` length.

OTOH the shift by 56 bits moves data outside the result's length as the offset exceeds the length of integer, so it certainly causes a loss of information, hence the warning.

Comment: `uint8_t` will be promoted to `int`. It will be signed, not unsigned, and it will be whatever width `int` is, which is commonly 32 bits these days but is permitted by the C standard to be 16 bits or more. This will not work “OK” because, if the high bit of the `uint8_t` is on and `int` is 32 bits, the shift by 24 bits will overflow the range of values representable in `int`, and the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 2):

Values with a type smaller than `int` are **promoted** to `int` when used in an expression.  Assuming an `int` is 32 bit on your platform this works in *most* cases when converting a 32 bit value.  The time it won't work is if you shift a 1 bit into the sign bit.

In the 64 bit case this means you're attempting to shift a value more than its bit length which is undefined behavior.

You need to cast each byte to a `uint64_t` in both cases to allows the shifts to work properly.